# Understanding memory usage concepts in java

Tags: java, memory, xml-parsing, runtime

I wrote a small program to parse an XML(SAX parser) file in java, just to check how much memory my program is consuming. I added the following line of code in a loop.

```
System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()+" = used memory");
```

I get the following output:

```
  <CATALOG>
243919216 = used memory
    <CD>
243919216 = used memory
      <TITLE>
243919216 = used memory
      <ARTIST>
243919216 = used memory
      <COUNTRY>
243919216 = used memory
      <COMPANY>
243919216 = used memory
      <PRICE>
243919216 = used memory
      <YEAR>
243919216 = used memory
```

Since I'm new to these memory concepts, I was wondering:

- What is the unit of this output (243919216 = used memory)?
- What is the optimum consumed memory for an application?
- Is this the proper way to check memory usage?

Answer (score 5):

> 1. What is the unit of this output (243919216 = used memory)?

It is a *long* value giving *number of bytes*

> 2. What is the optimum consumed memory for an application?

That answer varies from application to application.

> 3. Is this the proper way to check memory usage?

Nope. This doesn't give you the correct answer. Use a *profiler* to get this info. You might also want to replace `maxMemory()` with `totalMemory()` to get a *little closer* to the actual answer.

Comment: I'm confused if using statements like 

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> obj = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); 
consume more memory, that's the reason i wanted to check my memory status.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed - You shouldn't think about memory in that way.. Generics are just *compile-time* barriers that prevent you from using wrong types.

Comment: You mean creating a list of lists doesn't have any thing to do with memory consumption?

Answer (score 2):

Java uses a TLAB (Thread Local Allocation Buffer)  Each thread grabs a large block of memory from a common pool and allocates from this locally.  When you read the memory accounting, you can only see how much the common pool is using.

You can see the memory usage more accurately by disabling the TLAB with `-XX:-UseTLAB` on the command line.  This will allow you to see byte, by byte memory usage.

Note: this will not show you how much memory would be retained on a full collection, you need to do a `System.gc();` as well to see this, but you can see how much memory has been used.

> What is the unit of this output (243919216 = used memory)?

The memory usage is too course to be useful for small amounts, turn off the TLAB will help.

> What is the optimum consumed memory for an application?

The optimal amount is not additional memory, but this is not efficient for development effort.  Often it makes sense to waste a few dollars worth of memory to save a few hours of development time.

> Is this the proper way to check memory usage?

The easiest way to monitor memory usage is to use a memory profiler.  This is the best place to start as this will look at your whole application, not just the bits which your are focusing on.

Answer (score 1):

- The unit is bytes.
- There is no "optimum consumed memory for an application". All
  applications are different.
- No, that's not a proper way to check memory usage. That's what
  profilers such as `JMeter` and `JVisualVM` are for.

Answer (score 0):

Add -verbose:gc argument This argument will log GC occupancy information on the native stderr file or file where console output is redirected. Delete the existing file, Run the program till required.  Load the file in GCMV tool to check the memory usage behavior.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/gcmv/